# MySQL History of the result of the queries?

Tags: mysql, logging

Is it possible to see the history of the result of the queries? I know your query history is in `~/.mysql_history`, but I also want to see the result of those queries.

Comment: You would need to look at the transaction log.

Comment: It's not stored anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that the result of an arbitrary SELECT query could be many times larger than the database itself (think of cartesian products), those results are not automatically logged anywhere.

The result would also be subject to change, because other updates are constantly changing the data in the database. So the query result would only be relevant to the transaction that ran that query at that time.

If there's any logging of query results, it would have to be something your own application does deliberately. The plain `mysql` client (which uses `~/.mysql_history`) does not log results.